# SQL rollback transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to delete a data in a tables

```
BEGIN TRAN 

DELETE FROM TABLEA
DELETE FROM TABLEB

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

But when I check the data in the table, the data do exist.

Comment: Ahem..... well what did you *expect* ? You're deleting from two tables, in the context of a transaction. You then **roll back** that transaction - this means: all the changes made within that transaction **are not applied** to the database. So those data rows are **not really deleted** - that's the whole point of having transactions!

Comment: But he said it "do" exist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are rollbacking a transaction, you are cancelling the uncomitted changes.
If you open a transaction, delete, and rollback, the data will exists.

If you want to commit the transaction (delete the info), then do

```
BEGIN TRAN 

DELETE FROM TABLEA
DELETE FROM TABLEB

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some explanation about `TRANSACTION` in SQL Server

A transaction is a single unit of work. If a transaction is successful, all of the data modifications made during the transaction are committed and become a permanent part of the database. If a transaction encounters errors and must be canceled or rolled back, then all of the data modifications are erased.

Also bear in mind that using `TRANSACTION` temporarily locks the table so you must be careful.

```
 BEGIN TRAN 
    Statement1
    Statement2
 COMMIT TRAN
```

If one of the statement fails or have some error the `transaction` will `rollback` and ignoring all the statement and there will be no changes

When you use `ROLLBACK TRAN` it erase the  all data modification made from the start of the `transaction` use `COMMIT TRAN` instead

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

with

```
COMMIT TRAN
```

and the data will be deleted. `rollback tran` means canceling all changes made in the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN   

DELETE FROM TABLEA 

DELETE FROM TABLEB  

COMMIT TRAN  
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

If you have more than one action in a transaction, you should always use a try-catch block to rollback everything is one part of the transaction fails.

Answer (score 1):

--As a summary

```
BEGIN TRAN 

DELETE FROM TABLEA
DELETE FROM TABLEB

ROLLBACK/COMMIT TRAN
```

--ROLLBACK: in the name rollback, it will cancel the process.

--COMMIT: in the name commit, it will confirm the process.